# Object method return TypeError: not a function

Tags: node.js

I created a `Invitation` class inside `api.js` and used `module.exports = Invitation;`
with `const API = require('./api.js');` in my `app.js`.

```
class Invitation {

    constructor(code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.members = [];
        this.uses = 0;
    }

    get uses() {
        return this.uses;
    }

    get leaves() {
        return this.uses - this.members.length;
    }

    get real() {
        return this.uses - (this.uses - this.members.length);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the Invitation object from a map in my `app.js`
but when I call `invitation.uses()` the script crash with.

`TypeError: invitation.uses is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are JavaScript [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), which means you don't call them like regular functions. You can access the values by calling `invitation.uses` and not `invitation.uses()`.

Also, you should rename the instance variable or the getter itself, otherwise it won't work.

```
class Invitation {

  constructor(code) {
    this.code = code;
    this.members = [];
    this._uses = 0;
  }

  get uses() {
    return this._uses;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: The only issue I see with the code (which I missed the first time around) is that there is a naming conflict between the "instance variable" and the getter.

I'll edit my answer to reflect that.